# SpringBoot CBC ciphersuite and logjam vulnerability

Tags: spring-boot, security, spring-security

I have configured in Springboot the cipher suites:

The configuration that I have in my configuration file is:

```
server:
  ssl:
    key-store: /etc/keystore.keystore
    key-store-password: password
    key-alias: default
    trust-store: /etc/truststore.jks
    trust-store-password: secret
    enabled: true
    client-auth: need
    protocol: TLS
    enabled-protocols: TLSv1.2
    ciphers: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256,kEDH+AESGCM,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA,DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256,DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256,DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256,DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA,DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,!aNULL,!eNULL,!EXPORT,!DES,!RC4,!3DES,!MD5,!PSK
```

I have trying with all cipher suites that i have found in internet, but i always have the same, something like: "Overall Rating B"

Using the page: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

```
 TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH sect571r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS   128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH sect571r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS   256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   DH 1024 bits   FS   WEAK   128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)   DH 1024 bits   FS   WEAK   256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)   ECDH sect571r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH sect571r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK   128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH sect571r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH sect571r1 (eq. 15360 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK   256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x67)   DH 1024 bits   FS   WEAK   128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)   DH 1024 bits   FS   WEAK  128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x6b)   DH 1024 bits   FS   WEAK   256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   DH 1024 bits   FS   WEAK  256
```

I have a report with the vulnerabilities with:

```
CBC inseguro

Logjam
```

I have  tried all the solutions in internet, but I have the same result.

The environments is Using Springboot 2 in Ubuntu, (without apache or tomcat, ...) only with the embebed tomcat of the Spring.

Is possible solve that problem.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You could try disabling ciphers with AES_128 encryption I presume this should boost your score as you have no weak key-exchange algorithms like DSA or DES so only this comes to mind.